# How do i show a list from a model to another View in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of `Topic`'s. Each `Topic` have a list of `Message`. When i click on "Details" I want to open a new View that display a list of the `Message`'s from the Topic.

I expect that I need to modify this line: (this is what I have so far)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }, null)
```

The `Message`'s are accessed by `item.Message`.

And the first line in the Detail View

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.TopicMessage>
```

---

This is my Topic View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Topic>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }, null)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: I can't understand. You are creating links for each topic in that line. Do you want to display a partial view for Message list?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları I want to open a new View with all the Message this Topic contains.

Comment: Do you have a partial view for that?

Comment: I have only know MVC 4 for two days. I know partial Views is for views you can reuse in other views. But I thought here the first time I should just get it to work in a normal View before advange to Partial View, but that's maybe a bad strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by making a `somethingViewModel` that contained both the liste and the Id. That way i could contain the two information from two difference places in one new object I had access to in the View.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do that. You can use the `Action` method to execute the controller action directly:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.Action("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Or you can bypass the controller and render the view directly using [this overload of `DisplayFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407420%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Messages, "MessagesDetail")
    </td>
</tr>
```

Or if you define the template as the default `DisplayTemplate`, you can just do this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Messages)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Okay I will give it a try.
It's a good idea to make the View strongly typed right? It should be like this right?
@model IEnumerable<Models.TopicMessage>

Comment: @radbyx Yes, that's definitely preferred.

Comment: What about this instead @model IEnumerable<Models.Topic>? Im confused. Should I bring the Topic, that i could get the Messages from, or do I bring a list of Message?

Comment: @radbyx For a detail view of a single `Topic` entity, I'd generally recommend `@model Model.Topic`. This way you can enumerate the `TopicMessages` in that model or inspect other properties as well. If, however, this is *just* a list of messages (not exactuly a full detail view of the parent `Topic`), `@model IEnumerable<Models.Topic>` would be better, IMO. Of course, you might have a detail view which contains the list of messages, in which case you might have actually two views, but that's sort of up to your personal preferences.

Comment: I get this Error with #1 : " No overload for method 'Action' takes 4 arguments" Did you mean ActionLink?

Comment: @radbyx Sorry, the fourth parameter is for providing html attributes for the `<a>` tag. This isn't used in `@Html.Action`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I can't get Action to work. Now i tryed #2 with @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Messages, "MessagesDetail"), but I have no link to press on and I can't click the text either?

Comment: Im trying to building a forum, that have alot of Topics and each Topic have alot of Messages. I can display all my Topic's but i can't diplay/navigate to a new View that contain all the messages from one topic. Thank you for helping, I have only tryed MVC4 for two days now.